# State changes after Ember.computed finished

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember app that displays a list of borrowed articles in a table. One table cell has a select helper that has either 'borrowed' or 'returned' as value.

I also have a checkbox that triggers the showing of returned items via query Parameters.

When I set my checkbox to not show returned items and set one item from 'borrowed' to 'returned', the article will stay visible.

So what I will have to do is reload the 'filteredResults' with the state change incorporated.

I read about Ember.observer but I'm not sure it's the right thing to use for this.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['showReturned'],
  showReturned: false,
  possibleStates: ['borrowed', 'returned'],
  filteredResults: Ember.computed('showReturned', 'model', function() {
    const articles = this.get('model');
    if (this.get('showReturned')) {
      return articles;
    } else {
      return articles.filterBy('state', 'borrowed');
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to watch the `state` attribute on each `model` with `model.@each.state`.

```
filteredResults: Ember.computed('showReturned', 'model.@each.state', function() {
    const articles = this.get('model');
    if (this.get('showReturned')) {
      return articles;
    } else {
      return articles.filterBy('state', 'borrowed');
    }
  })
```

Along the same lines, if you wanted to just watch whether any articles were created or destroyed, you could watch the array - `'model.[]'`.

You want `Ember.computed` ([doc](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html)) because you are consuming the result as a property.  You would use `Ember.observer` ([doc](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/object-model/observers/))  if there was an action you wanted to perform every time one of the states changed (such as automatically saving the model).

Comment: This works perfectly! Also thanks for the explanation on the why.